# Bassed on certain vaulues in a column, update other column in another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the folowing dataframe,

```
Index   Col1    Col2  Col3   Col4
IDX1    MN      ABC   SHUITY
IDX2    CA      DAC   HUI
IDX3    IX      AAA   None
IDX4    JN      HSY   JHYW
IDX5    MO      AAA   None
IDX6    MN      AAA   None
IDX7    CA      AJDH        JDUE
IDX8    JX      SJYW        JSI
```

Please note whenever there is `AAA` in the values of `col3`, respective col value is `None` in `Col4`. I want to replace them with `AAA` in `Col4`. How do I do that?

Comment: Your column4 is empty?

Comment: Also, I only see AAA in column2, and None in column3. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: actually the column names got shifted. Its in col3 only

Comment: I want to put AAA in col 4 if there is AAA in col3

Comment: So column 4 is empty to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do this with `np.where` -

```
df['Col4'] = np.where(df.Col2 == 'AAA', 'AAA', '')
df

  Index Col1  Col2    Col3 Col4
0  IDX1   MN   ABC  SHUITY     
1  IDX2   CA   DAC     HUI     
2  IDX3   IX   AAA    None  AAA
3  IDX4   JN   HSY    JHYW     
4  IDX5   MO   AAA    None  AAA
5  IDX6   MN   AAA    None  AAA
6  IDX7   CA  AJDH    JDUE     
7  IDX8   JX  SJYW     JSI
```

It's possible `Col4` already has some values in them. In that case, a slight modification is in order.

```
df['Col4'] = np.where(df.Col2 == 'AAA', 'AAA', df.Col4)
```

The same values are retained if the cells do not need reassignment.

---

Alternatively, you may update with `loc` -

```
df.loc[df.Col2 == 'AAA', 'Col4'] = 'AAA'
```

Comment: Welcome back : )

Comment: @Dark Good to be back :-)